# Visual Studio 2008, Timer, c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, timer

If i want my application to do something every 2hr (eg. pop up a message), how do i do that?

Do i program that set of code under onLoad() or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming WinForms.

You should use Windows [`Timer Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Drag and drop timer component to your form.

Set interval to 7200000 (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds.

Subscribe to `Tick` event (the only event that this component has).

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Example");
}
```

The code inside of timer will be triggered every 2 hours, if UI thread is not blocked.

Comment: @zerkms - if you want to show popup messages why would you want to use `Timer` in `Threading`? Windows timer takes care of synchronization with UI thread.

Comment: @zerkms - in WPF it will be `DispatchTimer`

Answer (score 3):

Check the `Timer` Control and event `Tick`

[Timer.Tick - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class and set it up when the application starts.